# Issues getting specific Raspberry Kernel Sources from Github

Tags: kernel, modules

I have a Issue getting the Kernel Sources for the Raspberry from Github. To be clear, I have no Problem in getting them as such, but for a specific Kernel Version of the 3.10.y-Branch, lets say 3.10.28.

Here is what I did:

- Opened h***s://github.com/raspberrypi/linux
- Opened History for the "main" Makefile to get the git-Hashtag of the Source Version I want (*020abbc91120ddf052e2c303a8c598c3be4dc459* for 3.10.28)
- Performed checkout:

`git clone h***s://github.com/raspberrypi/linux.git`

- Performed switch to the wanted Hashtag/Version:

`git checkout 020abbc91120ddf052e2c303a8c598c3be4dc459`

I tried to compile my custom Kernel Modules with the Sources I checked out as described above "in the usual way" that I will not explain here in detail.

Now the major Issue: The Kernel Configuration Process (I use `make oldconfig`) asked much more Questions than usual, mostly for Directives marked as "NEW". These Questions were all related to the Target ARM Architecture, which is armv6 for the Pi.

It seems, that something was missing in the "arch/arm" Folder of the Sources. Indeed, there was no "mach-bcm2708" Folder which was required for my Kernel Config. Instead, there was only a "mach-bcm2835" Folder.

You can reproduce this by Comparing the Content of the "arch/arm" Folder on Github for the specific and the "generic" Tree:

https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/tree/020abbc91120ddf052e2c303a8c598c3be4dc459/arch/arm

The "mach-bcm2708" Folder is only available in the "Generic" Tree:

https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/tree/rpi-3.10.y/arch/arm

My Question is, why?

After some Investigations, I found Infos of some "Multiarchitecture" Approach for the different ARM Platforms in Linux.

Maybe its related to this, or rather an Github Issue in the Versioning/Merging with the Vanilla Kernel?